# String pattern matching

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I can't figure out how to solve this:

given two strings, one representing a pattern, one a random string, determine whether it pattern matches with the first string

ex:

```
string1: "aaba"
string2: "catcatdogcat"
```

thus, string1 and string2 are pattern matched

versus if string2 were `"catcatcatcat"` this would not be pattern matched.

Do this for any pattern and string.

I know it's recursion but I'm pretty stuck on... how to solve this

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] -- you are expected to make an effort and post your code. If you have no idea where to start (and this looks like homework), you should be consulting with your teacher.

Comment: @JimGarrison - I'm thinking recursion but I don't know what else. I'm trying to think of a general algorithm versus code. Not homework though, just practice with problem solving!

Comment: +1 I think this is a pretty good question. Not easy to implement such a thing.

Comment: What if you had a string like `"abcaoiecatcatdogcatoijeo"`, would that still match `aaba`?

Comment: Homework? I am not sure, but I think that we are hitting the NP-hard barrier here!

Comment: Do the the substrings, "cat" and "dog" have to be of equal length? That is, if the pattern if of length n, must the length of string2 be cn, where c is the fixed length of each word?

Comment: Should we assume that pattern `"abc"` matches *any* input at least 3 characters long?

Comment: @Geobits: No `abc` would match any string that has at least three **different** substrings.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Ah, right. catcatcatcat.

Comment: @Geobits: Ah, right. That would indeed match. The OP is asking for impossible rules. But one thing is sure: `aaa` would not match.

Comment: I meant that the OP mentioned `catcatcatcat` does not match `aaba`, so it was implied they had to be distinct and my question was already answered. I don't know that the rules are *impossible*, so much as unclear at this point. Both Sam and Cruncher make good points which would drastically change how hard/easy this is.

Comment: @Cruncher no they don't need to be! so "aacata" would match "aaba"

Comment: @user2457563 that's much harder

Comment: Does anyone want to try to do the reduction and prove the NP-Hardness of this problem? (or an algorithm to show that it's in P) (or both, but then you'll have solved P=NP :))

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm gonna try to explain a recursion for this,sounds right but I don't have a chance to test it ( not at home ).

Take a vector v['size of alphabet'], where v[i] = how many letters from string2 = letter i from string 1.

In you case in the end it is : v['a'] = 3, v[b] =3;

You initialise the vector with 1.

For the rec function:

You take the first letter from string1 : a;
Represent for a from string2 is the string that starts at string2 and ends at string2+v['a']; which is 'c';
You check if this is a valid solution untill now, and it is.

Then you go into rec( string1 + 1 ) , letter a again,
since v['a'] still = 1 then you take the second a as = 'a'.
You check if this is a valid soulution, and it is not because you have already defined the first a as 'c'.
You go back in the recursion and increment v['a'], start from the begging.

You take the first letter of string1 : a;
Represent from string2 which is 'ca' , ( now v['a'] = 2 )
check if valid.
rec ( string1 +1 );

and so on...
at a point you will reach v['a'] = 3 and v['b'] = 3;
then with the rec function you will find the solution.

I for one find it easier to implement in a interative function but you said something about recursion so yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Take the number of unique letters. Then you want to iterate through all combinations of possible lengths for each letter using the following constraints:

1. sum(length of letter * occurances of letter) has to be the length of string2
2. Each length must be at least 1

That is, for 2 unique letters, and a string length of 4, the possible lengths are:

(1, 3) and (2, 2)

From here it's simple. For each unique letter you can find out the string that letter must represent for the given string, as you know the length of each letter. Then it's a matter mapping each letter to the string it must represent, and if at any time a letter corresponds to a string that didn't match an earlier instance of it, then you have no match.

For your example:

```
string1: "aaba"
string2: "catcatdogcat"
```

Here, for the iteration where the lengths are (3, 3). Since we know a is of length 3, we know the first iteration of a must be "cat". Then the next a, corresponds to "cat" (still have a match). Then the next 3 have to correspond to b. This is the first b so it can match any 3 chars. Then match a at the end to cat again, and you're done.

If you want a,b,c to be unique as outlined in @MartijnCourteaux comment(and in your question now that I read again), then at the end you can just check your map for common values, if there are any common values then you have no match.

If you have a match at ANY iteration, then the string matches the pattern. There is only no match, if there is no match at ALL iterations.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to achieve:

Regex is the way to go. In Regex, there is something called a *backreference*. Backreferences *need* to match the very same string, the mentioned match group has already matched. i.e. the Regex `^([ab])\\1$` will match every String like `aa` or `bb`. The First group matches either a or b - but the backreference NEEDS to match the same thing, the matchgroup (in this case "1") matched.

So, all you need to do is: Convert your String-based pattern to a Regex pattern.

Example:

```
String regex = "^([a-z]+)\\1([a-z]+)\\1$";
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
   Matcher m = p.matcher("catcatdogcat");

   if (m.matches()){
     System.out.println("matches!");
     System.out.println(m.group(0));
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
     System.out.println(m.group(2));

   }else{
    System.out.println("no matches!");
   }
```

produces:

```
matches!
catcatdogcat
cat
dog
```

this will EXACTLY match your given string "catcatdogcat", while match Group 1 beeing "cat" and match group 2 beeing "dog".

What you now need to do is:

- Write a function, that checks your string pattern `aaba` char by char.
- First occurence of a letter: replace it with `([a-z]+)` and note the number of that matchgroup (Array, Hashmap, ...)
- Any further occurence of the letter: replace it with `\\1` (if the recorded number for the letter was 1)
- Wrap the result with `^` and `$`.

Finally, your String `aaba` will be converted to `^([a-z]+)\\1([a-z]+)\\1$` and serve your needs. The pattern `abccba` will become the regex `^([a-z]+)([a-z]+)([a-z]+)\\3\\2\\1$`

Finally use the matcher to check your given string.

This example assumes only lowercase characters, but you can extend it.

**however it is imporant to keep the "+", cause the "*" would allow zero length-matches, which will make your regex match about ALL THE TIME.**

Second example mentioned:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   String regex = "^([a-z]+)([a-z]+)([a-z]+)\\3\\2\\1$";
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
   Matcher m = p.matcher("catdogcowcowdogcat");

   if (m.matches()){
     System.out.println("matches!");
     System.out.println(m.group(0));
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
     System.out.println(m.group(2));
     System.out.println(m.group(3));

   }else{
    System.out.println("no matches!");
   }
  }
}
```

produces:

```
matches!
catdogcowcowdogcat
cat
dog
cow
```

edit: if needed (even if it does not 100% match your requirements - see comments):

```
public static String convertToRegex(String pattern){
    String regex = "";
    Map<Character, Integer> refs = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    Integer i=1;
    for (Character c : pattern.toCharArray()){
      if (refs.containsKey(c)){
         //known.
         regex += "\\" + refs.get(c);
      }else{
         //unknown
         regex += "([a-z]+)";
         refs.put(c, i++);
      }
    }

    return "^" + regex + "$";
  }
```

Comment: Your first example would match `catcatcatcat` since there's nothing to force the third match to be different from the first and second, that that was explicitly given as a non-match by the OP.  Also, consider the generalization: replace every occurrence of `[a-z]+` in your regexes with `.+` and see where that goes...

Comment: He said that he is practicing problem-solving in the comments, therefore I guess he was looking for an algorithm on doing it instead of a built in function.

Comment: @JimGarrison that's right. Must have overseen that example.

Comment: @JimGarrison But such `false positives` can be easily sorted out afterwards by comparing the matchgroups taken. (Adhoc i don't find an example, where such a false positve could also be matched in a true positive case)